# Cargar combobox comparando con un listbox

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox

Hola la cuestión es la siguiente.
Quiero cargar un combobox con horarios en un rango de 08:00 a 20:00 cada 30 min, solo si estos horarios no estan en un listbox.

De la siguiente manera.

```
    private void cargar_horas_disponibles()
    {            
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);
        TimeSpan fin = new TimeSpan(20, 0, 0);
        TimeSpan p = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);

        cboxhorasdisponibles.FormatString = "hh\\:mm";
        while (!(ts > fin))
        {
                            
            if (listBox_Horas_Ocupadas.Items.Contains(ts))
            {
                ts += p;
            }
            else
            {
                cboxhorasdisponibles.Items.Add(ts);
                ts += p;
            }  
        }
    }
```

Las horas en el listbox están por así "19:30"  (el formato lo di en la consulta de sql )

---------------------****--------------------------------------------

El problema ERA que no comparaba los registro del listbox para llenar el combobox.

En síntesis así como esta no funciona, probé manipulando las variables para que queden todos del mismo tipo y después hacer la comparación pero tampoco. Lo que si funciona es que el combo se carga siempre con el rango de horario completo.

Lo resolví creando una consulta sql que devuelva los horarios que necesito y así poder cargar el combobox. Hasta acá todo bien. Tengo 3 combobox uno me carga las especialidades, otro me cargas los médicos dependiendo de la especialidad, y el tercero carga las horas de la consulta anterior.

-----------------------------*****----------------------------------------

Dicho lo anterior ahora tengo una nueva pregunta, un nuevo problema.

Lo que estoy intentando hacer el es lo siguiente:
Es un sistema el cual tiene que agendar un turno.
Paciente,Especialidad,Medico,Fecha,hora,

Paciente : Lo cargo con una consulta sql
Especialidad : Lo cargo con una consulta sql
Medico : utulizo la especilidad seleccionada para cargar los medicos por esp.
Fecha : la saco de un monthcalendar
hora : La obtengo de una consulta sql (StockProc.)

Quiero que los cbox funciones de esta manera :

Cbox.Especialidades --------> Cbox.Medicos -------> Cbox.Horas_Disponibles

1_Que Cuando selecciono un elemento de Cbox.Especialidad me cargue Cbox.Medicos.

2_Que cuando seleccione un elemento de CBox.Medicos me cargue Cbox.Horas_Disponibles.

3_Que cuando Seleccione otro elemento de Cbox.Especialidad me restee CboxMedicos.

3.1_Que cuando seleccione otro elemento de Cbox.Especialidad me resetee Cbox.Horas_Disponibles (que muestre solo el dialogo sin ningun elemento).

Los puntos 1,2,3 funcionan.

El punto 3.1 es donde tengo el problema, ya que una vez cargados los datos de Cbox.Horas_Disponibles quedan ahi, solo se modifica el contenido del cbox si selecciono un medico y una fecha que tenga "horas ocupadas" entonces el cbox me muestra las disponibles.

La consulta que utilizo para las horas disponibles es la siguiente :

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(5),horas_operativas, 108) Horas_Disponibles FROM tmp_horas_operativas 
EXCEPT 
SELECT CONVERT(char(5),T.fechaturno, 108) Horas_Disponibles FROM Turno T 
INNER JOIN TurnoPaciente TP 
ON T.idTurno = TP.idTurno Where TP.idMedico = @varidmedico and (select CONVERT(char(8),T.fechaturno, 112)) = @fecha
```

A la consulta le encontré una problema, y es que cuando la @varidmedico es NULL o 0 (cero) me devuelve todas las horas de la tabla horas_operativas.

Intente primero solucionar en el formulario con un if, y no tuve buen resultado.
Cree un Stock Procedure con la consulta y un if, y en principio ejecutandola como Query en server y funciona de maravilla.
Cuando pongo el StockProcedure o la consulta en el form. hace lo mismo que comentaba anteriormente. Me muestra todos los horarios de la tabla como si estuviera recibiendo un null o un 0.

Comment: A simple vista el codigo parece tener sentido, ¿Puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/455114/edit) la pregunta para explicar el problema que se te está presentando?

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: Ahora confunde más, no está claro si lo resolviste y ahora tienes otra pregunta. O si la pregunta ahora es diferente a la original.

Comment: Fíjate ahí si esta mas claro, si no avísame, Gracias